# Weblate component Discovery API not Works

Tags: api, curl, add-on, weblate

When I create a `weblate` addon (component discovery) with the REST `API`,

```
**'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" ' +
'-H "Authorization: Token **************" ' +
'-k -d "{' +
'\\"name\\":\\"weblate.discovery.discovery\\",' +
'\\"configuration\\":{' +
'\\"match\\":\\"locales/(?P^<language^>[^^/]*)/(?P^<component^>(?!__TEMPLATE__) ([^^/])*)\\\\.json\\",' +
'\\"file_format\\":\\"i18next\\",' +
'\\"name_template\\":\\"{{ component }}_fr\\",' +
'\\"base_file_template\\":\\"locales/fr/{{component}}.json\\",' +
'\\"new_base_template\\":\\"locales/fr/{{component}}.json\\",' +
'\\"language_regex\\":\\"^^[^^.]+$\\",' +
'\\"copy_addons\\":true,' +
'\\"remove\\":false,' +
'\\"confirm\\":true,' +
'\\"preview\\":true},' +
'\\"url\\":\\"\\"' +
'}" http://127.0.0.1/api/components/repositoryname/__template__fr/addons/'**
```

`weblate` does not automatically get the files that I push in the `git` repository.

To make it work, I first need to manually

1. go to the discovery addon webpage in the web browser,
2. save the addon in the web browser
3. accept the list of files that match the template in the web browser.

Once this has been done one time, all the files that I push in the `git` repository are correctly discovered by `weblate`.

However we would like to do the 1), 2) & 3) steps automatically with the REST `API`.

I tried to set the confirm and preview fields of our `CURL` request to false but it does not work.

Is there a way to configure the `CURL` request so that `weblate` discover the files without any manual steps?

Warm regards.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I've [just added](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/commit/da1ba0986becab697fa034ef94115b598473f45a) test to cover this to our test suite.

My guess would be that something is wrong in the JSON request - maybe something is not properly escaped or is escaped too much?

What does the curl request end with? What Weblate version do you use?

PS: The version info was [posted here](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/discussions/7001). You need to upgrade, this has been fixed in [b9646f23174](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/commit/b9646f231744feeebde5ce758a1b57946756b6e3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer .
I have upgrade weblate to the last version and now it work.
Thanks .